# How to get number of connected users and their role using j_security_check?

Tags: jsf, java-ee-5, j-security-check, userprincipal

I get the username of the connected user (using j_security_check) this way, through a managed bean:

```
......
    username =   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

And then display it in a jsf page this way : `#{userBean.username}`
But I figured no way to get the **number of connected users** and get their role.
In other words, I want to display besides the username, the user role and the **number of connected users.**
How can I achieve this!?
Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:
I can now get the Role of the connected user, using a namedquery in a managed bean :

```
public Users getUserRole(){
      try {
            Users auser = (Users)
            em.createNamedQuery("Users.findByUsername").
                    setParameter("username", getRemoteUser()).getSingleResult();
            return auser; 
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(nre, "getUserRole Error");
            return null;
        }

    }
```

and in the xhtml page:

```
<h:outputLabel for="rolefacet" value="Role: "/>
  <h:outputFormat id="rolefacet" value="#{UserBean.userRole.ugroup}" />
```

while ugroup is the role name in the Users entity class.

---

EDIT: One solution that still does not work for me is to add a HttpSessionListener to my web.xml:

```
package beans;

/**
 *
 * @author med81
 */

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;


public class SessionCounter implements Serializable, HttpSessionListener {

    private List sessions = new ArrayList();
   Object  s =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);

    public Object getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(Object s) {
        this.s = s;
    }


    public SessionCounter() {
    }


    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        sessions.add(session.getId());

        session.setAttribute("counter", this);
    }


    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        sessions.remove(session.getId());

        session.setAttribute("counter", this);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return size of the session list
     */
    public int getActiveSessionNumber() {
        return sessions.size();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a basic kickoff example how you could do it when you're on Servlet 3.0 and thus are able to utilize programmatic login by the new `HttpServletRequest#login()` API.

The login form: `login.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{user.username}" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{user.login}" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

The user manager bean: `com.example.UserManager`

```
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserManager implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private User current;

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;

    @ManagedProperty("#{loginManager.logins}")
    private Set<User> logins;

    public String login() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(username, password);
            current = userService.find(username, password);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // Unknown login. Will be handled later in current==null check.
        }

        if (current == null) {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login"));
            return null;
        } else {
            logins.add(current)
            return "home?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }

    public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "login?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    // ...
}
```

The logout (and session invalidate) listener: `com.example.LogoutListener`

```
@WebListener
public class LogoutListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        UserManager userManager = (UserManager) event.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        if (userManager != null && userManager.getCurrent() != null) {
            userManager.getLogins().remove(userManager.getCurrent());
        }
    }

}
```

*(Do not do this in `logout()` method! It's the session invalidation which triggers this, the session invalidation will take place when `logout()` is called OR when session has expired)*

In any logged-in view you can obtain the current user and the login count as follows:

```
<p>Welcome, #{user.current.name}!</p>
<p>Total logged in users: #{user.logins.size()}</p>
```

Comment: Wonderful! I guess there remains only one small edition : from `<h:commandButton value="#{user.login}" />` to `<h:commandButton action="#{user.login}" />` and adding getters for (password,username,logins). Many Thanks again @BalusC! You're the best!

Comment: I fixed the button (sorry, there's no IDE-like autocompletion in Stackoverflow editor). The getters/setters are covered by `// ...` comment, I assume it to be obvious enough :)

Comment: what if I have no choice like JavaEE5 (WebSphere 7) and JSF 2. How would I achieve the same thing i.e. request.login(...)?

Comment: How long is the information maintained in the Set<User> logins ? When does the content expire ?

Comment: @Stephan just Ctrl+F "remove".

Comment: @BalusC yes i have noticed the logout as also the remove() . Let me rephrase my question please. How can i assure that the session maintaining the list with the logged in users (in this case  Set<User> logins;) will be maintained forever (until the application shuts down).  Won't the session expire at some point and the information get lost ?

Comment: @Stephan Where did you read that `LoginManager` must be session scoped?

Comment: Any suggestions on making this work on a clustered environment?

Comment: @SeanCoetzee Just let `LoginManager` store data in a shared datastore.

Answer (score 8):

> *get the number of connected users*

I'll assume that you mean to get the number of logged-in users.

Basically, you need to have an applicationwide `Set<User>` with all logged-in users and add the `User` to it when it logs in and remove the `User` when it logs out or when its session is destroyed. Here's an example which uses an application scoped managed bean

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoginManager implements Serializable {

    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

}
```

If you were using **Java EE 6** it would have been easy to replace `j_security_check` by a managed bean method which utilizes the new Servlet 3.0 [`HttpServletRequest#login()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and simultaneously adds the `User` to the `Set<User>` of the injected `LoginManager` bean.
But on **Java EE 5** there is no trivial way to hook on it. You would need to check every request for the logged-in user. Best to achieve this is to put the `User` object in the session whenever there's an `UserPrincipal`. You can do this using a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which does roughly the following job in `doFilter()` method.

```
UserPrincipal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

if (principal != null && user == null) {
    user = userService.findByName(principal.getName());
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    LoginManager loginManager = (LoginManager) servletContext.getAttribute("loginManager");
    loginManager.getUsers().add(user);
}
```

Finally, to remove the user from the logins, best is to hook on [`HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29), assuming that you're invalidating the session on logout. This will also be called when the session expires.

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    User user = (User) event.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    if (user != null) {
        LoginManager loginManager = (LoginManager) event.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("loginManager");
        loginManager.getUsers().remove(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I'll be trying this solution tomorrow and give my feedback!  I had in mind a similar approach (Using a class that implements HttpSessionListener and two three methods : void SessionCreated(), void SessionDestroyed and int getActiveSessionsNumber() {return sessions.size(); }but your solution seems better! Let's try!

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to get the login count in the view by `#{loginManager.count}` or something if you supply a `getCount()` method which returns `users.getSize()`.

Comment: Yes it has: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29 Inside a `Filter` you only need to cast the `ServletRequest` back to `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: ok! Yea it does! I was using the wrong attribute! Sorry! 
One other thing, where did the servletContext come from? Declared in the Filter class : ServletContext servletContext = .....something; ??

Comment: `request.getServletContext()`.

Comment: could you please @BalusC add a second answer (HttpServletRequest#login() and simultaneously adds the User to the Set<User> of the injected LoginManager bean ) taking in consideration that I am using Servlet 3.0 now. If not so much asked !!!