# Getting list of all users that are currently connected

Tags: java, jsf-2, facescontext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSF J_security_check How to get number of connected users and their role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141237/jsf-j-security-check-how-to-get-number-of-connected-users-and-their-role)

I already know that this line takes care of getting the current logged-in user in a JSF 2 application:

```
     connectedUserName = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

Is there any way can I get a list of all users that are currenty logged-in the web JSF 2 application?

Thanks in advance...