# Programmatic login into jsf application

Tags: forms, jsf, authentication

I found examples of programmatic login into jsf based application, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6598326/1331274) from Balusc.
Maybe it is silly question but, when I use form based authentication, I can use only a simple html form with

```
<input id="username" type="text" name="j_username" />
<input id="password" type="password" name="j_password"/>
```

in `<form method="post" action="j_security_check">` form.

I cannot use jsf form from example, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not JSF who handles the login, it's the container itself. The JSF `<h:form>` does not allow you to specify a specific action URL. So you have to use `<form>`.

But your question title is confusing. Using a `j_security_check` form is **not** "programmatic login". It's "container managed login". The *real* programmatic login way is calling `HttpServletRequest#login()` *yourself*. You can do this in a JSF managed bean action method which is invoked by a JSF `<h:form>`.

Comment: Hard to admit then I feel dumb. I determine in web.xml in <form-login-config> section <form-login-page>/login/loginSimple.xhtml</form-login-page>. When I try to make programmatic jsf login page whit appropirate managed bean - loginSimple.xhtml, than it not work at all :(

Comment: Then you're using container managed login. You should then indeed use a plain `<form>`. You do not need to do anything in JSF for this.